# Material UI Grid drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to convert my Material-Ui Grid to a drag and drop grid. I already tried to convert it with the `react-grid-layout` package, but it makes weird result. What is the simple way to make the Material Ui grid drag and droppable.

My grid looks like that :

```
<Grid
   container
   spacing={2}
   direction="row"
   justify="flex-start"
   alignItems="flex-start"
  >
    { widgets.map(elem => (
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} key={widgets.indexOf(elem)}>
         { elem }
      </Grid>
    ))}
</Grid>
```

Comment: I use `react-grid-layout` extensively and without any issues. What do you mean that it gives weird results?

Comment: Like, i grab the card and there is an offset between my card and my mouse cursor. Like this issue, but there  is no answer on it : https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/720

Comment: What version of React is being used?

Comment: The 16.11 version. I really want to implement a react grid with drag and drop.

Comment: On the github issue that was attached in the comment before, it seems that the React version is an issue. Give it a shot with React 16.5?

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: Could you provide a sandbox with your solution?

Answer (score 3):

had same issue with react-grid-layout as you. workaround is to wrap grid with relative-positioned div

```
        <div style={{position: "relative"}}>
            <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
        </div>
```